# Electron event for when the page content is changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

What is the correct event to use for when the page content is changed?
I tried using `web-contents-created` but it's only called whenever I either start the app or open devtools, but it does not run when I press a button that (for example) leads to another web page.
I also read the docs, but I couldn't find any other events similar to this.